# Linq Efficiency question - foreach vs aggregates

Tags: linq, performance, aggregate

Which is more efficient?

```
//Option 1
foreach (var q in baseQuery)
{
  m_TotalCashDeposit += q.deposit.Cash
  m_TotalCheckDeposit += q.deposit.Check
  m_TotalCashWithdrawal += q.withdraw.Cash
  m_TotalCheckWithdrawal += q.withdraw.Check
}

//Option 2
m_TotalCashDeposit = baseQuery.Sum(q => q.deposit.Cash);
m_TotalCheckDeposit = baseQuery.Sum(q => q.deposit.Check);
m_TotalCashWithdrawal = baseQuery.Sum(q => q.withdraw.Cash);
m_TotalCheckWithdrawal = baseQuery.Sum(q => q.withdraw.Check);
```

I guess what I'm asking is, calling Sum will basically enumerate over the list right? So if I call Sum four times, isn't that enumerating over the list four times? Wouldn't it be more efficient to just do a foreach instead so I only have to enumerate the list once?

Comment: I ran the test that Lasse suggested and found that having one foreach loop rather than multiple Sums is more efficient by a significant amount. Thanks Lasse and thanks Duck for running the test and providing further support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might, and it might not, it depends.

The only sure way to know is to actually measure it.

To do that, use BenchmarkDotNet, here's an example which you can run in [LINQPad](https://linqpad.net) or a console application:

```
void Main()
{
    BenchmarkSwitcher.FromAssembly(GetType().Assembly).RunAll();
}

public class Benchmarks
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void Option1()
    {
//        foreach (var q in baseQuery)
//        {
//            m_TotalCashDeposit += q.deposit.Cash;
//            m_TotalCheckDeposit += q.deposit.Check;
//            m_TotalCashWithdrawal += q.withdraw.Cash;
//            m_TotalCheckWithdrawal += q.withdraw.Check;
//        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Option2()
    {
//        m_TotalCashDeposit = baseQuery.Sum(q => q.deposit.Cash);
//        m_TotalCheckDeposit = baseQuery.Sum(q => q.deposit.Check);
//        m_TotalCashWithdrawal = baseQuery.Sum(q => q.withdraw.Cash);
//        m_TotalCheckWithdrawal = baseQuery.Sum(q => q.withdraw.Check);
    }
}
```

[BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) is a powerful library for measuring performance, and is much more accurate than simply using Stopwatch, as it will use statistically correct approaches and methods, and also take such things as JITting and GC into account.

---

Now that I'm older and wiser I no longer belive using Stopwatch is a good way to measure performance. I won't remove the old answer, as google and similar links may lead people here looking for how to use Stopwatch to measure performance, but I hope I have added a better approach above.

**Original answer below**

<strike>Simple code to measure it:</strike>

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// your code here
sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Time taken: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
sw.Reset(); // in case you have more code below that reuses sw
```

You should run the code multiple times to avoid having JITting having too large an effect on your timings.

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and profiled this and found that you are correct.

Each Sum() effectively creates its own loop.  In my simulation, I had it sum SQL dataset with 20319 records, each with 3 summable fields and found that creating your own loop had a 2X advantage.

I had hoped that LINQ would optimize this away and push the whole burden on the SQL server, but unless I move the sum request into the initial LINQ statement, it executes each request one at a time.